# How can I get rid of weather marks on Trex decking?

Tags: decking

We got some Trex decking in great shape, except it was originally installed upside down! So, there are marks on the 'wood grain' side where the board contacted the joists. Is there a way to get rid of those marks?

Comment: Are the marks discoloration,  or are they indentations from pressure from above. ?

Comment: What makes you think it was upside down? The original Trex didn't have an upper face, if I recall correctly. Occasionally you could detect slight cupping to the boards, but I don't believe that was an intentional design characteristic

Answer (score 1):

The original Trex product fades over time and with sun exposure since it's partially composed of wood fibers. Conversely, it may darken where fungus is allowed to grow, such as where it contacts other lumber.

I'd expect the weather marks to lessen in a few months or a year. I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect to remove them, though some of the contrast may be due to soil and fungus. Try a pressure washer with some detergent and then give it some time to even out.

If that fails to provide a good outcome, a penetrating [stain can be applied](http://www.carydeckrestoration.com/deck-staining/can-you-stain-composite-decking-trex-decking/) to create a more uniform appearance.